# Current monitor shows overload even for small load

Tags: current-measurement, load

I have a current-shunt monitor using [INA202](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina202.pdf) between a 5V power supply and loads. The current monitor should turn off a MOSFET switch and disconnects the loads if the load current goes over 150mA.

I have problem when I connect one of the loads. It is an [accelerometer](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL335.pdf) (which should consume only 350µA), powered via a 2.5V LDO regulator. Whenever I connect it, the current monitor shows overcurrent and disconnects the loads. But it doesn't happen if I first connect the accelerometer and then power on the power supply. Also it doesn't have the problem with other resistive loads.

I solved the problem by putting a resitor and zener diode, making a 4.3V regulator, in front of LDO. Although it solves the problem, I didn't understand what was causing the problem. I would like to know what could be the cause.

Edit: Here is the rough circuit:

[image]

Comment: rough sketch of schematics

Comment: Inrush current, maybe? Your series resistor is limiting that.

Answer (score 2):

The accelerometer datasheet states that the turn-on time is proportional to the values of Cx, Cy and Cz (Note 7 on page 3 pasted below)

*(7 Turn-on time is dependent on CX, CY, CZ and is approximately 160 × CX or CY or CZ + 1 ms, where CX, CY, CZ are in microfarads (μF)).*

This implies that these capacitors have to charge up at power-up, giving your circuit a short term inrush current. This is not at all unusual in a [Hot Swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping) environment.

When the device is connected at normal power-up, these capacitors are charging at the same time as the voltage is rising, masking the effect of the output capacitors.

If you want to do hot swap, I would suggest using a device specifically designed for the task. A number of vendors have these, and this is [a typical device](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4215).

HTH